# Multi-user data contamination in C# solution

Tags: c#-4.0, session-state

I have this Web Developer app that sends list data to another set of .aspx/aspx.cs files like this:

```
                Session.Add("Selected-List-Details", Selected-List-Details);
                Server.Transfer("new-file-name.aspx");
```

The problem, however, is if more than one user tries to do something at the same time, data is getting cross-contaminated between the 2 sessions.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a simple workaround? Am I overlooking a useful session function?

Comment: Cross contamination? Do you mean when a user modifies the selectedlist-details,  is this session object a static property?

Comment: The session objects gets some data from Session 1 and other data from Session 2. I guess what I'm asking is -- is there a way to identify the session by some ID and make sure my new-file-name.aspx page knows this list data is only associated with this particular session?

Comment: How did you define the selected list details in your application  ? Add that class to the question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(v=vs.90).aspx.    seems to show how to send the session id with your server.transfer

Comment: I think I found my answer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx